# How to use 2 translations at 1 function Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in which I need to make 2 translations for the Russian and English versions. I have done it simply:

```
'message' => trans('notify.bust_withdraw') . $get->amount .  X =   . $cashout .  trans('notify.bust_nostart')  . $profit . ,
```

But i received erorr:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''. $get->amount . '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'
```

`X =`  it's static word, without translate.

Why i received error? Where can be my mistake?

**EDIT:** my full code:

```
Notify::create(
[
'user_id' => $this->user->id,
'title' => 'Crash Game',
'message' => trans('notify.bust_withdraw') . $get->amount .  'X ='   . $cashout .  trans('notify.bust_nostart')  . $profit ,
'status' => '1',
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$message = trans('notify.bust_withdraw') . $get->amount .  'X ='   . $cashout .  trans('notify.bust_nostart')  . $profit;
Notify::create(
[
'user_id' => $this->user->id,
'title' => 'Crash Game',
'message' => $message ,
'status' => '1'
]);
```

I added string literals for the static string "X = " and removed the . at the end since there are no more concatenations

Comment: now i received `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''status'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'`. i edit my question with information about full code

Comment: I removed the comma after the 'status => '1'  and tried to initialize message before creation to have a better understanding

Comment: and i has same question, what's wrong here? `'message' => trans('notify.craft_win') . $summa .  trans('notify.craft_summ') trans('notify.craft_chance') . $chance .  trans('notify.bust_win'),` , and i received error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'trans' (T_STRING), expecting ']'`

Comment: Maybe it needed to have parenthesis () around the concatenation, Or maybe because of the extra comma